# Range of function Involving Modulus Quantity.

Tags: inequality

> If $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}\;,$ Then Range of $$\frac{|x+y|}{|x|+|y|}+\frac{|y+z|}{|y|+|z|}+\frac{|z+x|}{|z|+|x|}\,$$ 
>   $\bf{My\; Try::}$ Here $x,y,z$ Not all Zero Simultaneously.

Now Using $\bf{\triangle\;  Inequality}\;,$ We get $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$

Similarly $|y+z|\leq |y|+|z|$ and $|z+x|\leq |z|+|x|$

So we get $$\frac{|x+y|}{|x|+|y|}+\frac{|y+z|}{|y|+|z|}+\frac{|z+x|}{|z|+|x|}\leq 3$$

Now I did not understand How can I calculate $\min$ of that expression, Help Required

Thanks

Comment: Since all the moduli are non-negative that function is always greater than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No two of the numbers may vanish simultaneously, otherwise one of the terms becomes $\frac{0}{0}$.

If all three numbers have the same sign, then the expression becomes $1+1+1 = 3$, so the upper bound you found is attained.

If one of the numbers - by symmetry let's say $x$ - is $0$, you have

$$\frac{\lvert 0+y\rvert}{0 + \lvert y\rvert} + \frac{\lvert y+z\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert + \lvert z\rvert} + \frac{\lvert z+0\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert + 0} = 2 + \frac{\lvert y+z\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert + \lvert z\rvert} \geqslant 2.$$

So let's look at all numbers nonzero, but not all having the same sign. Since the expression is invariant under multiplication with $-1$, and by symmetry, we can assume that $x < 0 < y \leqslant z$. Then $\lvert y+z\rvert = y + z = \lvert y\rvert + \lvert z\rvert$, whence

$$\frac{\lvert x+y\rvert}{\lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert} + \frac{\lvert y+z\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert + \lvert z\rvert} + \frac{\lvert z+x\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert + \lvert x\rvert} \geqslant \frac{\lvert y+z\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert + \lvert z\rvert} = 1.$$

Choosing $y = z = 1$ and $x = -1$ attains that lower bound. So the range is contained in $[1,3]$. By connectedness of the domain and continuity, the range is exactly $[1,3]$.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean when you say "So let's look at all numbers nonzero, but not all having the same sign. Since the expression is invariant under multiplication with $−1$, and by symmetry, we can assume that $x<0<y⩽z$."

Comment: @user350331 We have dealt with the case that one of the numbers is $0$, and the case that all three numbers have the same sign before. It remains to look at the case where all three numbers are nonzero, but not all have the same sign, so there is at least one negative number, and at least one positive among them. Since the expression is unchanged if we multiply each of the three numbers with $-1$, it suffices to look at the case of one negative number and two positive numbers. Since the expression is invariant under permutations of the three numbers, we can label them so that $x<0<y\le z$.

Comment: Whoa, that was some rigorous analysis, how do you come up with these ideas, is it experience or is there something that I can refer to too which builds my intuition for examining symmetric expressions.

Comment: Experience @user350331. And a bit of laziness that makes looking for ways to save work attractive.

Answer (score 3):

We need not just that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are not all zero simultaneously, but that no two of them are zero; otherwise the expression is not defined.

At least two variables have the same sign, so at least one term is $1$. The others are non-negative, so the minimum is at least $1$. Since $1$ is attained (e.g. for $1,1,-1$), this is the minimum.